# Got response code '401' in logstash. If restart it automatically disappear

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

can i know why i am getting response code '401'. Everything look fine. After i restart logstash again this does not happen

I am using docker-compose

```
[2021-08-18T04:49:18,326][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][2b6d754adc23b7c8ea56f9a46472ea071a1e60f0a221ed2f896a7d3e34026d00] Elasticsearch setup did not complete normally, please review previously logged errors {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'https://es1:9200/_ilm/policy/logstash-policy'", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError}
```

Answer (score 0):

these may help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224289

[BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63913279)

elastic environments

```
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "logstash_system"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: => "l12345"
```

and
logstash config

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        user => logstash_system
        password => l12345
        index => "logs-topic"
        workers => 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the same config, and it is not working.